# Get python idle to run in interactive mode without command line switch

Tags: python-idle

I'm writing a lesson for an introduction to programming course. I'm using the turtle module and I would like to have run a program in interactive mode. It seems that the only way to do this is start IDLE from the command line with the `-n` switch. Is there a way to do this just using the GUI?

Edit:
[In the Python documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/turtle.html?#module-turtle) They mention this:

> It tries to keep the merits of the old turtle module and to be (nearly) 100% compatible with it. This means in the first place to enable the learning programmer to use all the commands, classes and methods interactively when using the module from within IDLE run with the -n switch.

By running `idle3 turtle_practice.py -n` from the command line I can write commands in the python shell like `forward(100)`  and the turtle will move.  Is there a way I can be able to do this(type commands in the shell and have the turtle move) without having to run IDLE from the command line?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  IDLE always runs programs from the editor in 'interactive mode' (the equivalent of -i at the command line).  This has nothing to do the the -n ('no separate process') startup switch.  The latter means that IDLE runs user code in the same process as IDLE, instead of a separate process.  This is generally less dependable, which is why it is only a backup mode.

Comment: In other words, try explaining what you want more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I didn't need to run IDLE from the command line with a switch to do this, just running it normally allowed me to do what I wanted to do.

Comment: That is what I said should be the case.  Since there is no question, consider deleting this non-question.